# How to create a restorable PostGIS/PostgreSQL database backup with pg_dump?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, maintenance

I am unable to restore a database backup when the database contains schema's that contain geometry datatypes or postgis functions.

During restore, I get the spatial_ref_sys relation not found error. The backup file that pg_dump sets search paths that do not include the public schema.

Is there a way to produce a file that is restorable? Or will the backup file always require manual modification of the `SET search_path =` statement?

Answer (score 1):

Run following command in cmd.

```
pg_dump -F c -h ip -p port -U user  -v databasename> path/file_name.dump
```

ip= Database IP address.

Port= Port of DB(5432 default)

user=DB user

databasename=name of your database.